# You're still in sleep/sleep mode

Tags: word-usage

A person's who just woken up is still really sleepy and walks into a wall. So the other person says:

> You're still in sleep.

> You're still in sleep mode.

To mean: You're still sleepy.

Does the first sentence work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, possible as a joke.  Machines and computers have "modes".  Humans don't have "modes" so it is a figurative use of language to say "you are in sleep mode".  This kind of joke or figurative language is very common, even if this particular phrase is not.

For example I'll sometimes comment that someone is "In French mode" if they have returned to the UK from their hometown in France (it can take a little time to get used to speaking English again.) It is not intended to be a serious comment.

In plain, boring English "You're still asleep" is the normal way to say it.

Comment: So "in sleep" sounds unnatural, right? (Without "mode" in the end)

Comment: If "sleep" is the name of a state something can be in, then you can say "in *sleep*" - it's the exact same construction as "in *sleep mode*". But that's not in common use, and most people wouldn't know what you were referring to, so it would just sound like you were talking about sleep in general (and using the wrong preposition)

Comment: @cactustictacs in sleep? I don't think so. You are still **asleep**.

Comment: @Lambie exactly! It's not a phrasing people are familiar with so it just sounds like you're talking about sleep, rather than Sleep.

Comment: @cactustictacs It is not English.

Comment: @Lambie it's totally English.  It only makes sense in a contrived artificial context, but it's definitely English.

Comment: @phoog It is not English at all to say: "you are still in sleep"; "You are still in labor": Yes. it is not idiomatic, it is not accurate and furthermore, it hurts the ears.We say: You are still **asleep**. I really dislike repeating myself but I dislike outrageous notions more.